# how to fix import error in terminal, but in eclipse works fine

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, cmd, import

I got this estructure, that works in eclipse, but I got a import error in cmd. I tried sys.append.path but it does not works. 
I´m running main.py

```
python main.py
```

In eclipse running the same code, ctrl+f11, it works fine.

```
Principal\__init__.py
Principal\lib\_init__.py
Principal\lib\functions.py
Principal\App_user\__init__.py
Principal\App_user\main.py
Principal\App_user\controller\__init__.py
Principal\App_user\controller\User_Controller.py
```

I got in User_Controller.py, `from Principal.lib import funcionesDB` it works in eclipse but it doesn't in cmd.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 175, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 119, in main
from controlller.User_controller import User_Controller
File "C:\Users\NCB-APD\Desktop\Proyects\Apps\Aplicaciones\Principal\App_User\controller\User_Controller.py", line 21, in <module>
from Principal.lib import funcionesDB
ImportError: No module named Principal.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change you directory to where you code is, and then run it in cmd line like: python main.py, or you may need to specify the directory of your code just like: python "path of code"/print_test.py.